# How to find if the app is running within facebook or outside of facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

How can we find using PHP or Javascript if the facebook app is running within Facebook or running outside of Facebook as a Website. Am not sure what should be the criterion to check?

Comment: I have a facebook app that runs as both a Facebook App and a Website that uses Facebook Login. Both have the same codebase. What I would like to acheive is to dynamically know which version of the app is the user using [Facebook or Website]?

Comment: try to catch the server name, i think which will help you a lot. once your runs through facebook you will able to know the server name id facebook, am i clear ?? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] using php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some checking. The answer below works:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["signed_request"]){
// Opened in facebook
}else{

//opened outside facebook.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for signed_request is not enough. 
In case of more pages, navigation is in frame and you lose the signed_request parameter.

First check for signed_request in first page, then put in session a bool variable and do controls on this.

This approach has a problem: if you open another tab and visit app in Facebook (or viceversa), you will share the session :)